# Como sumar los valores de un array multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php

Quisiera saber teniendo este array en PHP

```
array (size=5)
  94 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '7' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => string '7' (length=1)
      3 => string '7' (length=1)
  95 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => string '6' (length=1)
  96 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
      3 => string '5' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
  99 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '3' (length=1)
      4 => string '3' (length=1)
      5 => string '3' (length=1)
  105 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
```

como sumar los valores de cada grupo de forma tal que me quede de esta forma:

```
array (size=5)
  94 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '28' (length=1)      
  95 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '18' (length=1)
  96 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '25' (length=1)      
  99 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '18' (length=1)      
  105 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '8' (length=1)
```

Para despues poder multiplicar el valor de la suma obtenida por el valor externo del array de esta forma:

```
94*28
95*18
96*25
99*18
105*8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas fácil que veo es utilizar [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) con [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php).

En una línea

```
$b = array_map("array_sum", $array);
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php
$arr = array (
    94 => array (
      0 => '7',
      1 => '7',
      2 => '7',
      3 => '7',
      ),
    95 => array (
      0 => '6',
      1 => '6',
      2 => '6',
      ),
    96 => array (
      0 => '5',
      1 => '5',
      2 => '5',
      3 => '5',
      4 => '5',
      ),
    99 => array (
      0 => '3',
      1 => '3',
      2 => '3',
      3 => '3',
      4 => '3',
      5 => '3',
      ),
    105 => array (
      0 => '4',
      1 => '4',
      ),
);


$b = array_map("array_sum", $arr);

print_r($b);

// Multiplicar
foreach ($b as $clave => $valor){
    echo $clave * $valor."\n";
}
```

Resusltado:

```
// Suma
Array
(
    [94] => 28
    [95] => 18
    [96] => 25
    [99] => 18
    [105] => 8
)

// Multiplicación
2632
1710
2400
1782
840
```

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas, era lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando la función **array_sum()**:

```
$arr = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]];

foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $arr[$k] = array_sum($v);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Da como resultado:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(10) }
```