# Sumar 2 array vector por vector

Tags: php

Necesito crear una funcion en la que sume 2 array, y que el resultado lo almacene en una variable VR;

Con las siguintes lineas logro la suma, pero la impresion del resultado tengo mucha informacion

```
    $V1 = array(1, 2, 2, 4, 3);
    $V2 = array(5, 6, 7, 3, 4);

    $VR = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $VR[] = $V1[$i] + $V2[$i];
    var_dump($VR);
```

Con estas ciclo for logro realizar la suma pero necesito que el resultado sea solos los numeros sumados.

Ejemplo  **$VR = 6,8,9,7,7**

Pero el resultado lo visualizo de la siguiente manera;

```
[0]=>
  int(6)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(6)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(6)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
  [2]=>
  int(9)
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(6)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
  [2]=>
  int(9)
  [3]=>
  int(7)
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(6)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
  [2]=>
  int(9)
  [3]=>
  int(7)
  [4]=>
  int(7)
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como sumar los valores de un array multidimensional en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92938/como-sumar-los-valores-de-un-array-multidimensional-en-php)

Comment: El `var_dump()` está dentro del for y se muestra en cada iteración. Colócalo después del ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

Como resultado de tu suma estas obteniendo otro array que estas almacenando en el array $VR para poder mostrar tus datos como quieres, lo puedes hacer recorriendo nuevamente ese nuevo array con un bucle o sencillamente accedes a los datos a través de sus indices.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo para que puedas comprender como hacerlo.

```html
for ($j = 0; $j < count($VR); $j++) {
    echo $VR[$j];
}

echo "$VR[0], $VR[1]";
```

Answer (score 0):

para lograr tu propósito solo tenes que darle el formato para que se muestre, podes lograrlo de diferentes maneras, un ejemplo seria con sprintf().

```
$V1 = array(1, 2, 2, 4, 3);
$V2 = array(5, 6, 7, 3, 4);

$VR = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
   $VR[] = $V1[$i] + $V2[$i];
   echo sprintf('%d,',$VR[$i]);
}
```